# How to add a TabBar in AppBar in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, user-interface, dart

I have a AppBar as defined below. I want to add a TabBar below it. When i try to supply it in the `bottom:` property of the AppBar it throws a renderflex error:
This is my code:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 2,
      child: Scaffold(
          body: Stack(
        children: [
          Positioned(
            top: 15,
            left: 15,
            right: 15,
            child: SafeArea(
              child: ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                child: AppBar(
                  title: Text('Hello', style: kTasksStyle),
                  centerTitle: true,
                  backgroundColor: kGreen,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      )),
    );
  }
```

This is what the appBar looks like:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are trying to this

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final List<Tab> myTabs = <Tab>[
      Tab(text: 'LEFT'),
      Tab(text: 'RIGHT'),
    ];
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 2,
      child: SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text("Hello"),
            centerTitle: true,
            bottom: TabBar(
              tabs: myTabs,
            ),
          ),
          body: TabBarView(
            children: myTabs.map((Tab tab) {
              final String label = tab.text.toLowerCase();
              return Center(
                child: Text(
                  'This is the $label tab',
                  style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 36),
                ),
              );
            }).toList(),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

[image: Outupt]

Comment: I’ve tried this but I want the app bar to be a part of the stack and float over the page. The above solution won’t let me do that. Do you have any other ideas ?

Comment: did you ever work this out ? we need same